# Is it polite/good manners to say 'whatever'?

Tags: word-usage, politeness, formality, informal-language

If I'm being in *formal* speaking, do you think it's ok to use word ***whatever***?

I think this word somehow doesn't fit a good conversation especially when talk to the *olders*. I feel like it gets a bit careless intonation whenever I use it .

> I will consider whatever you choose

Would it get the same meaning with

> I will consider anything you choose

Because I tend to see this word used in informal conversation (like teen stuff you know...)

> Yeah whatever you choose

In my country (culture) we could also use only a word to express the kind of word, but we tend to make it a bit longer to get it formal, something like :

> Yes you can choose anything, I will consider every single of them

not just *whatever*

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer to your question so quickly, but you may want to wait a little longer before accepting it. This post on meta explains why: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/

Comment: Who or what do you mean by *"the olders"*? Do you mean *people older than me*, *older people*, *the elderly*, *seniors*? All of these are more natural and idiomatic than *"the olders"*, which native speakers do not use.

Comment: If I'm being honest, Yes, at the time (actually the whole time) I asked questions on this site, I think I want some more "answers" coming since this is about language ("people need more explanations"). I agree I accepted the answers a bit hurry.

Comment: And the *olders* is actually *elderly seniors*, my mistake (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Whatever" is quite OK to use in a polite conversation, as long as you speak in complete sentences. "I will do whatever you want" is fine. "Whatever" on its own sounds dismissive- you don't think that the person you are talking to deserves a complete sentence.

"Consider" is something that your elders, your boss or your bank manager say: it means "I might accept your suggestion, I might reject it". If you are a respectful junior, you "accept" or "take notice of".